# Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest [400] while creating index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

In my rails application with 'elasticsearch-model' and 'elasticsearch-rails' gems installed and elasticsearch (v5.1.1) running on the default port and a model that looks like this

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  field :title, type: String
  field :author, type: String

  index_name "articles-#{Rails.env}"
end
```

And the initializer is something like this

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] || "http://localhost:9200/"
```

When I try to import or create index

```
Article.import force:true
Article.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true
```

I get the following error

```
 Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest: [400] No handler found for uri [//articles-development] and method [DELETE]
  from /Users/bgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:201:in `__raise_transport_error'
  from /Users/bgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:312:in `perform_request'
  from /Users/bgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/faraday.rb:20:in `perform_request'
  from /Users/bgr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some investigation the issue was with my initializer. it worked after changing the host.

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host: ENV['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] || "localhost:9200"
```

**Update**
Apparently the configuration works with Elasticsearch 2.4.x.

Comment: hi @GirdharBandi am new to rails can you please tell me where to add this line.

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique you can create a file in config/initializers/ and add your config to that.

Comment: What a wonderful answer. Indeed removing the http just worked fine

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, changing DATABASE_URL format, in `.env` or wherever You keep it, from:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres:/myapp_development?pool=5
```

to:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/myapp_development
```